# Source Formatting Tool for OSX?

Tags: html, code-formatting

I run on OSX and I don't have Dreamweaver. I use Coda but I need an HTML Source Formatting tool. Is there a web-based tool or other app for me?

Answer (score 1):

I can name a few. When I run OS X, I use (if available):

- [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)
- [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)
- [Kod](http://kodapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a decent online editor, take a look at [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/index.html) or [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). They're definitely worth the 90 seconds to see if it fits your needs and its better than some software editors I've seen. [This question also lists more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367099/best-online-code-editor-with-a-textarea), as [does this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755130/what-is-the-best-online-code-editor-supporting-html-javascript-css) [FixMyHtml](http://fixmyhtml.com/) is good if you need to quickly reformat some code before editing it elsewhere.

---

**Software Editors:**

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is amazing, but it's up to you to decide if it's worth 57$ after the free trial. [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) is 200$ and isn't as good as TextMate. According to their website:

> "What sets BBEdit apart is its extensive professional feature set including Web authoring capabilities and software development tools."

In other words, BBEdit just for HTML editing is probably a bad choice.

---

Here's some free ones besides Coda that you mentioned:

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) is good and light-weight. Incidentally it was made by BareBones software, who also make BBEdit.

[Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/) is the newer version of Nvu, but its primarily designed for WYSIWYG. I recall the html editing to be decent though.

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is eclipse's html editing extension, also it also runs without eclipse. Its fairly heavyweight, but its pretty good and has plenty of useful features. If you're familiar with eclipse it's a great choice.

Haven't used: (free unless otherwise mentioned)

- [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) 25$
- [pagespinner](http://www.optima-system.com/pagespinner/)
- [TacoEdit](http://tacosw.com/)
- [WebDesign](http://www.ragesw.com/products/webdesign.html)
- [KOD](http://kodapp.com/)

**[Wikipedia's list of html editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors), [free OS X html editors](http://www.usingmac.com/2007/12/16/free-html-editors-for-mac-os-x)**

Good luck!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cloud based code editor, look at [Ace editor](http://ace.ajax.org/), formerly Mozilla Bespin/Skywriter.